# Adding mat-divider to mat-select/mat-option

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design

Is it possible to have a mat divider (a horizontal line seperating two mat-options)?

I have tried:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
   <select matNativeControl required>
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <mat-divider></mat-divider>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

A bad workaround I have now is:

```
<mat-option>--------------------------</mat-option>
```

However this is not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how exactly you want the divider to appear, but a pure CSS approach would be to overwrite the `.mat-option` class on your main `styles.css`, make use of the `:after` [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after), and add a value to the `border-bottom` CSS property.

```
.mat-option:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(3em - 2px);
}
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i9nizj?file=app/select-overview-example.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using `mat-divider` itself by just adding `ng-container` to wrap `mat-option` and `mat-divider`. Then use the `last` `ngFor` [local variable](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) to conditionally remove the `mat-divider` from the last `mat-option`.

```html
<mat-select>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let food of foods; let last = last">
        <mat-option [value]="food.value">
            {{food.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
        <mat-divider *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
    </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-with-divider).

Comment: Yeah this answer works too.. If you aren't using ng-container you can put the mat-divider inside the <mat-option> tag e.g  <mat-option   *ngFor="let food of foods; let last = last"  [value]="food.value">
            {{food.viewValue}}.  <mat-divider *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
        </mat-option>    that also works too.

Comment: @Antonio you could do that, however, there will be a padding for the divider in that case. So it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, It is possible to add mat-divider to mat-select/mat-option

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label> Cars </mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option value="volvo"> Volvo </mat-option>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-option value="saab"> Saab </mat-option>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-option value="mercedes"> Mercedes </mat-option>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-option value="audi"> Audi </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: This has the major problem if the selection covers more than one line and the height will be unset. Because than it will appear in the middle of the selection box.

Answer (score 0):

Angular material Select documentation provide you help for that, you can use the panelClass directive like the example they show:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Panel color</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="panelColor"
              panelClass="example-panel-{{panelColor.value}}">//panelColor.value if you want to handle some class dynamically
    <mat-option value="red">Red</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="green">Green</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="blue">Blue</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and these are the css classes they handle

```
.example-panel-red.mat-select-panel {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.example-panel-green.mat-select-panel {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.example-panel-blue.mat-select-panel {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

So, you can apply wentjun css properties in a class

Comment: This will make the whole panel a particular color. It does not answer the question.